# Android - ListActivity, add Header and Footer view

Tags: android, header, footer, listactivity

I'm using ListActivity, listview.

```java
listView = getListView();
```

just working perfectly. I added footer view as

```java
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
listView.addFooterView( inflater.inflate( R.layout.footer, null ), null, false);
```

and everything was shiny but ugly, so i wanted to add this footer view (which contains only 1 edittext and only 1 button ) to header of listView as

```java
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
listView.addHeaderView( inflater.inflate( R.layout.footer, null ), null, false);
```

and suddenly everything goes wrong, and i get RuntimeException immediately.

```java
Suspended(exception RuntimeException)
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent)
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent)
ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, Activity$ActiviyRecord, Intent),
so on..
```

Why is it throws exception ? What is different between addFooterView and addHeaderView, and how can i add Header to ListActivity ?

UPDATE

So as you can read in comments, my logcat still doesn't work, but i just tried next at this moment:

```java
} catch(Exception e){ 
  Writer result = new StringWriter(); 
  PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
  e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
  String error = result.toString(); 
}
```

and afterward i put breakpoint, and i can read error in expressions section. it said :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
```

it was instructive for all of us. After change sort of commands, it works perferctly.

Comment: @add full logcat here...

Comment: logcat doesn't working at all :S never worked to me

Comment: @Victor: "logcat doesn't working at all :S never worked to me" - You mean you don't know how to access the logcat data? Start any emulator or connect a phone to the PC and use DDMS in eclipse and you'll see every app that's running will be outputting data to logcat.

Comment: @MisterSquonk i mean, logcat doesn't report anything

Comment: @Victor: Then catch the exception with `catch(Exception e)` and in the catch block use `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: but only things that i was modified is change addFooterView to addHeaderView. and addFooterView works everytimebut 'addHeaderView' doesn't

Comment: @MisterSquonk i did. and unfortunately it _really_ doesn't report anything

Comment: You need to learn how to use the tools. You are intentionally preventing getting the debugging information you need, by suspending execution at the exception. Do not do this. Allow the application to crash, and your stack trace will appear in LogCat.

Comment: Do not blame me please. LogCat still doesn't work. I find a way to read error, i updated the question. Thanks !

Answer (score -6, accepted):

so if you want to add header view to your listView, you should do that severely before use setListAdapter() or else it causes an IllegalStateException.

Comment: You answered your own question 2 weeks after anticafe provided the same answer, just to select it as the correct answer. That's not in the spirit of SO at all.

Comment: Yeah, if you read comments and updates, you can see that i found the answer on my own. I wanted to answer the question but i wasn't able to because of my low reputation. After all, you mark down my correct answer. That's not in the spirif of SO at all.

Comment: No victor, you didn't put any comment saying so in the first place. And even if you did, you should be thankful that somebody made a clear answer for you.

Comment: Dear E. Gunyar. 
Nobody made a clear answer for me, and clearly, you have absolutely no idea what you are talking about. Anyway, this question was asked 3 years ago... don't want to be so important please.

Answer (score 11):

As you log

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list --
>   setAdapter has already been called.

Listview's method **addHeaderView** or **addFooterView** must be called before **setAdapter**.

Comment: yep, i wanted to add answer too, but i have to wait 8 hour to answer my own question because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Create layout xml for header and footer

header_layout.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="header"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

footer_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:text="footer"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

now in activity java file onCreate() method add

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, listView,
            false);
    ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, listView,
            false);
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    listView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```